# Nesting foreach with data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multi dimensional array with the structure:

- Name
- Address
- Area

  - Area Type 1
  - Area Type 2
  - Area Type 2

I have a loop that grabs the Name and Address for each business and echos them out. Now what I want to be able to do is now grab the area and chuck that out for each business. My loop thus far is as follows:

```
foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {
    echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>';
            echo $value['Name'];
        echo '</li>';
        echo '<li>';
            echo $value['Address'];
        echo '</li>';
    echo '<li>';
                    foreach ($data as $row) {
                        echo $data['Area'];
                    }
        echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
}
```

I can output all the Areas in one go with:

```
    foreach($data as $row)
        {
           foreach($row['Area'] as $areaout)
              {
                 echo $areaout;
               }
         }
```

But I need it to echo out with it's respective name and address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you simply replace

```
foreach ($foo as $row) {
   echo $foo['Area'];
}
```

by

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($value['Area'] as $v) {
   echo '<li>' . $v . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>'
```

?